# How do I access an environment variable in a .desktop file's exec line?

Tags: linux, freedesktop.org

My program requires an environment variable as part of one of its parameters:

```
myprogram --folder=$HOME/.special
```

However, if I put this into a .desktop file's exec line, it doesn't work:

```
Exec=myprogram --folder=$HOME/.special
```

The $HOME seems to resolve to nothing.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

By default environment variables do not seem to be resolved by all implementations, however you can instead exec sh, which will resolve the passed environment variable.  Note that the desktop spec also requires you to escape the = and $ character with a backslash.  So you want:

```
Exec=sh -c "myprogram --folder\=\$HOME/.special"
```

For the full list of characters that need escaping, see [the specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables)

Comment: When your characters are in the string, you do not need to escape any characters.

Comment: I need to try this trick, but I love it. Here is an IMO slightly more readable version of the spec, https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/#exec-variables .

Comment: This worked perfectly for my use-case, which was predeclaring a variable before the command was run: `Exec=sh -c "FOO='bar' /path/to/exec"`

Comment: Nice work! I prefer using `bash` instead of `sh`, but it's pretty much the same thing. Here's the bash version: `Exec=bash -c "myprogram --folder=$HOME/.special"`.

Comment: You could use `exec` to avoid having an additional shell process running: `Exec=sh -c "exec myprogram --folder=$HOME/.special"`.

Comment: It works for `Exec`, but it doesn't work for values `Path` or `Icon`.

Comment: What id you already have an Exec for the .desktop program like `Exec=/home/coyote/anaconda3/bin/spyder %F` but then I want also `Exec=sh -c "LD_LIBRARY_PATH\=/usr/local/lib/:\$BOOST/lib:\$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial"`

Comment: More definitive description of the Exec key: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s07.html