# xdg .desktop file shell expansion

Tags: linux, shell, gnome

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to create a `something.desktop` file in `~/.local/share/applications` that successfully executes the command `chromium --user-data-dir=$(mktemp -d)` every time

The relevant line in the .desktop file is the `Exec` entry in the following example:

```
$ cat ~/.local/share/applications/something.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Name=chromecognito
Exec=chromium --user-data-dir\=\$\(mktemp -d\)
Icon=chromecognito
Type=Application
Categories=GTK;GNOME;Utility;
```

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980464/how-do-i-access-an-environment-variable-in-a-desktop-files-exec-line), which references [this document](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables) and tried various combinations of escapes of `$`, `(`, `)`, `=`, `"`, etc. in the `Exec` line, as well as working with single quotes, but haven't been able to get it to use a new temp directory **every** time the program is started from the "start menu"

As a side note, using the line `Exec=/home/myuser/bin/chromecognito` where `/home/myuser/bin/chromecognito` looks like this:

```
$ cat /home/myuser/bin/chromecognito
#! /usr/bin/env bash

(chromium --user-data-dir=$(mktemp -d) &)
```

works, although I haven't even successfully been able to use a tilde like `~/bin/chromecognito` for the Exec entry in the .desktop file. Maybe that's is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Exec=sh -c "chromium --user-data-dir=$(mktemp -d)"
```

Please note that both $(cmd) and ~ would be interpreted by the shell, so you must call a shell first to make those symbols work.

Comment: That's it! Interestingly, I didn't need to escape the `$` or anything else, which, based on the above linked question and xdg-specification, I wouldn't have expected.