# KDE service menu issues

Tags: linux, bash, kde-plasma

I have this .desktop file in /home/user/.local/share/applications

```
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=AudioVideo;Video;
Comment=This Bash script compresses the specified video files (wildcards supported) to lossy h.264 format in an MP4 container
Exec="\\$HOME/Scripts/Git/compress2mp4.sh" %F
GenericName=Batch compress to mp4
Icon=folder-video
MimeType=video/x-msvideo;video/quicktime;video/mpeg;video/mp4;
Name=Compress to mp4
NoDisplay=false
Path=
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=true
TerminalOptions=\s--noclose
Type=Application
Version=1.0
X-DBUS-ServiceName=
X-DBUS-StartupType=none
X-KDE-SubstituteUID=false
X-KDE-Username=
```

which shows up in the "Open with" menu and works flawlessly.

Then I created another .desktop file and copied it in /home/user/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
MimeType=video/x-msvideo;video/quicktime;video/mpeg;video/mp4;
Icon=folder-video
Actions=compress2mp4
X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel
X-KDE-StartupNotify=false
X-KDE-Submenu=Video


[Desktop Action compress2mp4]
Name=Compress to mp4
Icon=video-mp4
Exec="$HOME/Scripts/Git/compress2mp4.sh" %F
```

The service menu shows up but gives this error:

```
Could not find the program '$HOME/Scripts/Git/compress2mp4.sh'
```

I tried to replace `$HOME` with `\\$HOME` and `~/` but it did not help.
If I type `/home/my-user-name/...` instead of the `$HOME` there is a window opens up in the background and closes up right away so I can't catch what is going on there.

Does anyone have an idea on why a .desktop file `Type=service` does not work while a very similar file `Type=application` works?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that environment variables are not evaluated by `.desktop` file processors, as evidenced by similar problems posted online. If anything, it looks that KDE understanding environment variable in `/home/user/.local/share/applications` is a bug.

For one possible workaround, see [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8980464/3552063). Personally, I created service menu with following entry and it did work as expected (pay attention to placement of quotation marks):

```
Exec=sh -c "$HOME/bin/test.sh %F"
```

If I use absolute path to script in `Exec`, it does show something that could be mistaken for "window in background". Name of process appears on taskbar (which usually shows only windows) and quickly disappears. In my case, that was because my test script had only one command inside and finished execution almost instantaneous. How long do you expect your program to run? Have you verified that it does not finish successfully?

If you don't want to use `sh` workaround and don't want to use absolute path inside `.desktop` file, consider placing your script in one of directories in `$PATH`, where `.desktop` file processor will look for it. You can see value of that variable from plasma point of view by using following command:

```
tr '\0' '\n' < /proc/$(pidof plasmashell)/environ
```

Comment: Hello Miroslaw, Thank you for your help. Unfortunately your workaround didn't work for me. I also tried to copy the script to /usr/local/bin but that did not work either. I kind of gave up on the service menus for now and use "Open with" instead. Good thing about "Open with" that it works from another applications e.g. picture viewers while service menu works from dolphin only